# how can i extract axios data from string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

This is response data from server

```
[{"username": "harry"}][{"id": 1, "name": "playlist1", "tag": "genre"}, {"id": 2, "name": "playlist1", "tag": "genre"}, {"id": 3, "name": "playlist3", "tag": "genre"}][{"1": ["https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273503143a281a3f30268dcd9f9", "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27369fa55f10c5293bbb985c1af"]}, {"2": ["https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273503143a281a3f30268dcd9f9", "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27369fa55f10c5293bbb985c1af", "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273503143a281a3f30268dcd9f9", "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27369fa55f10c5293bbb985c1af"]}, {"3": ["https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273503143a281a3f30268dcd9f9", "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27369fa55f10c5293bbb985c1af", "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273503143a281a3f30268dcd9f9", "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27369fa55f10c5293bbb985c1af"]}]
```

With axios, data comes as a string in the format as above.
There are three arrays in the above string, and I want to extract each one separately and store it in a variable.

It doesn't converted to JSON. How can I get the data of username and the data of the second array? I tried to access it by index, but since it is a string format, it is accessed one by one letter

Comment: Whatever server's giving you that response is broken. Fix the server, then `JSON.parse` it

Comment: Also once you fix the response at server and response's header `content-type` is `application/json` axios will automatically parse it and give it to you.

Answer (score 0):

The response you have posted, is not a string. It appears to be three arrays, each containing x amount of objects.

A string can be identified, by being enclosed in either double: " " or single qoutes: ' '.

You can identify the arrays by the opening and closing square brackets: [ ].

The objects can be identified by the opening and closing curly brackets: { }.

Here is a bit more readable version of your response. I have annotated each top level array, with a comment, for easier identification.

```
// array 1
[
    {"username": "harry"}
]

// array 2
[
    { "id": 1, "name": "playlist1", "tag": "genre" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "playlist1", "tag": "genre" }, 
    { "id": 3, "name": "playlist3", "tag": "genre" }
]

// array 3
[
    { 
        "1": [
            "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273503143a281a3f30268dcd9f9", 
            "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27369fa55f10c5293bbb985c1af"
        ] 
    },
    { 
        "2": [
            "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273503143a281a3f30268dcd9f9",
            "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27369fa55f10c5293bbb985c1af",
            "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273503143a281a3f30268dcd9f9",
            "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27369fa55f10c5293bbb985c1af"
        ] 
    },
    { 
        "3": [
            "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273503143a281a3f30268dcd9f9",
            "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27369fa55f10c5293bbb985c1af",
            "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273503143a281a3f30268dcd9f9",
            "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27369fa55f10c5293bbb985c1af"
        ]
    }
]
```

The third array appears to contain an object, with a list within it. Like somebody else mentioned earlier, this seems like faulty data, and I would have a look at the source, instead of trying to parse it. That being said, it isn't impossible to loop through each list, and extract the data, but it wouldn't be the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should get response fixed as sugguested by @certainperformance and @ambianbeing, but **if you can't and still want to extract data from this string response** you can do it by doing something like this

```js
const axiosResponse = `[{"username": "harry"}][{"id": 1, "name": "playlist1", "tag": "genre"}, {"id": 2, "name": "playlist1", "tag": "genre"}, {"id": 3, "name": "playlist3", "tag": "genre"}][{"1": ["https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273503143a281a3f30268dcd9f9", "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27369fa55f10c5293bbb985c1af"]}, {"2": ["https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273503143a281a3f30268dcd9f9", "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27369fa55f10c5293bbb985c1af", "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273503143a281a3f30268dcd9f9", "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27369fa55f10c5293bbb985c1af"]}, {"3": ["https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273503143a281a3f30268dcd9f9", "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27369fa55f10c5293bbb985c1af", "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273503143a281a3f30268dcd9f9", "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27369fa55f10c5293bbb985c1af"]}]`;

const result = JSON.stringify(
  JSON.parse('{ "data": [' + axiosResponse.split('][').join('],[') + ']}').data[1]
);

console.log(result);
```